# @font-face works in mac all browsers, but not windows ff and i.e

Tags: css, font-face

This should be simple but it just doesn't work, I have the following code from Font Squirrel:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ResagokrRegular';
src: url('resagokr-webfont.eot');
src: url('resagokr-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('resagokr-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('resagokr-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('resagokr-webfont.svg#ResagokrRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ResagokrBold';
    src: url('resagokrbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('resagokrbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('resagokrbold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('resagokrbold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('resagokrbold-webfont.svg#ResagokrBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ResagokrLight';
    src: url('resagokrlight-webfont.eot');
    src: url('resagokrlight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('resagokrlight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('resagokrlight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('resagokrlight-webfont.svg#ResagokrLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

It works in all mac browsers but not in ff or i.e. on windows, chrome works in windows by the way. Not sure where I went wrong tried changing ' to " and still nothing.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 0):

pretty limited with info given, but if it's not working in ff and ie, i bet its in your headers: add this to your .htaccess file:

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot

AddType font/ttf .ttf

AddType font/otf .otf

<FilesMatch ".(ttf|otf|eot)$">

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

</IfModule>

</FilesMatch>

ref:  http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/07/fixing-firefox-font-face-cross-domain_25.html

if you're still having problems with IE, i'll bet it's IIS issue